# Как правильнее проектировать БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

Задали в унике сделать базу данных агенства недвижимости. Как поступить было бы правильнее и почему?
У нас есть агенты и клиенты, которых я планирую связывать через таблицу "сделка". Нужно ли делать для них отдельные таблицы? Или внутри них одно и то же и можно объединить в одну таблицу? Если да, то как описать, кто есть клиент, а кто агент? И стоит ли брать в учет ситуацию, что агент в теории когда-то мог быть клиентом и данные о нем уже лежат в базе?

п.с. не смотрите на названия, они для не англоговорщего препода, потом будут изменены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте про нормализацию БД и нормальный формы https://habr.com/ru/post/254773/

Comment: Есть такие термины как "анализ предметной области", "нормализация данных" и "построение ER-диаграммы". Вот они-то и описывают, как проектировать БД.

Comment: Бесполезная статья. Говорит "как", но не говорит "почему именно так". К тому же предполагает, что у читающего уже есть определённая, и немалая, база знаний, что может быть неверным, и не указывает, где эту базу набрать, если она отсутствует.

Comment: самое главное в ответе - это то, что упомянутая нормализация базы данных отвечает на вопрос. Дублировать теорию считаю нецелесообразным. Тем более, что в вопросе не спрашивается что-то конкретное. Само словосочетание можно загуглить в случае если ссылка пропадет.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Схема]

В этом случае все норм соединяется и работает. В одной таблице клиенты, в другой агенты и в сделках они соединяются. И "И стоит ли брать в учет ситуацию, что агент в теории когда-то мог быть клиентом и данные о нем уже лежат в базе?" - ну тут будет две разные сущности(клиент и агент, хотя это кажется одним и темже). И нужно дублировать в обеих таблицах.

В одну таблицу (Клиент/агент) можно и связать таблицей статусов, но незнаю как будет со связыванием клиента и агента по сделке. (Таблицы : Люди - Статус(Клиент/агент) - Сделка    и каскадом их соединить, будет такое себе).